# how to prevent .plist file name from showing

Tags: iphone

I am making a multi- timer app that uses plist files. the plist files are loaded into a tableview. I don't want the .plist extension from showing in the tableview. Is there a solution for this? 
Here is the code that I need help with. this is a NSArray not NSString

```
self.files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"Timers1"];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString * filenameWithExtension = @"timer1.plist";
NSString * filename = [filenameWithExtension stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

returns a string without extension.
You can set the string as table content.

```
cell.textLabel.text = filename;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm at work and not at my mac here is the part of the code that I'm working with. this is the original code I did change it to retrieve the plist files from a folder so it would'nt get the info.plist. self.files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"plist" inDirectory:nil];

Answer (score 1):

The tableview only represents the data, in this case the file name with is a NSString.  Before you set the cells contents just rename the string

```
NSString *filenameWithExtension = @"timer1.plist";
NSString *filename = [filenameWithExtension stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString:@".plist" withString:@""];
cell.textLabel.text = filename;
```

There are other String/Path helpers that can help you achieve the desired effect too.